# Log-Sobolev on an incomplete manifold

Tags: analysis, manifolds, entropy

Maybe my question is a nonsense but I prefer to ask.

Take $M$ a manifold that is not complete (ie the exponential is not defined for all
values of $TM$) and $V$ a potential defined on such manifold.

For example : take the cylinder $S^{d-1} \times [0,1]$ and a potential $V(\theta,t) = |\theta|^2 + t^2$.

Is there a result like Bakry/Emery's one, ensuring a log Sobolev inequality ?
I assume that there are conditions on the Ricci curvature and the hessian of the potential.
Maybe something is happening at the boundary...

Thanks in advance !